# insertion 74G data into mysql table cost more then 2 days, how to improve insert performance

Tags: mysql, insert

insertion 74G data into mysql table cost more then 2 days, how to improve insert performance.

table t1 as follow:

```
+-------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | varchar(50)    | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| value | varchar(10000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dt    | int(11)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

sql like this: `insert into  t1 values(XX,XX,XX),(XX,XX,XX),(XX,XX,XX),....(XX,XX,XX)`

Comment: do you have index on this table? it may help to disable the indexes, and add them after the index. but general i think a `load data infile` would be faster then one or multiple insert statements.

Comment: Make sure the inserts are done locally instead of over the network. Get better hardware (high performance ssd).

Comment: @Rufinus I have no index on this table except primary key id.

Comment: @hofan41 in our production , inserts only can be done overnetwork. But ssd may be a good idea

Comment: Then make sure that network is fast :) . Another way you can potentially speed things up is by splitting your dataset into multiple servers. perhaps you can have a separate db server for id's that start with a-h, for instance, while i-z can go to a different db server.

Comment: could you please show my.cnf?

Comment: Are you sending the whole 74G in one `INSERT` statement or in multiples? I do not yet know whether or not that matters, MySQL could be smart enough to perform an insert after each `,` instead of waiting for the last character of the statement, but it still might matter with respect to the transaction behavior.

Comment: Also, do you know if inserting something that is just 50% or 25% of the size takes 50% resp. 25% of the time, or significantly less? I'm asking to understand how it scales, maybe that could rule out some things and point to some others, i.e. it would mostly rule out slow network and point to an issue with indexes, transaction size or statement parsing.

Comment: Do you have any indication that the performance problem is related to MySQL itself and not something else like slow network? It would have to be awfully slow, but still. 74G in 2 days is roughly 450 kiB/s, that's very slow but that would be typical WLAN speed if there are collisions or interference. You're not trying to do a 74G insert via 11 MBit/s, poorly configured or massively used WLAN, I hope...

Comment: @ChristianHujer thanks for your reply. 1.Through analysis log, I found that insert speed go slower while the size of table grows huge 2.Every insertion contains 5000 values  3. The mysql server may be the bottleneck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What might be slowing down things significantly is the `VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY` in two ways:

- The `PRIMARY KEY` being active during insertion slows insertion down. Normally this doesn't matter and is the desired behavior because of the other things the `PRIMARY KEY` does, but for bulk `INSERT` operation of 74G the `PRIMARY KEY` might just be in your way, performance wise.
- The `PRIMARY KEY` being a `VARCHAR(50)` makes a slow `PRIMARY KEY`.

Personally I would try to avoid using `VARCHAR` for `PRIMARY KEY`.

### How `PRIMARY KEY` slows down `INSERT`

The `PRIMARY KEY` is a unique index which is used frequently. An index speeds up things for reading. There are many read access operations which need to compare, for example `JOIN` queries and `WHERE X = Y` queries. Without an index, these queries need to resort to linear search, which is `O(n)` with `n` being the number of rows in the table in question. That is slow. With an index, these queries resort to smarter algorithms which usually have a best case access time of `O(C)`, means constant access time, in case a hash could be used and there are no collisions, and `O(log2(n))` if due to hash collisions a sorted list or tree needs to be walked to find the exact match.

But the index comes at a prize. An index needs to be maintained (complex). Plus in case of a unique index, duplicates need to be avoided (trivial).

You should imagine the index like a sorted list. Let's compare a normal table and an index.

In a *normal table*, new entries would simply go to the end of the table. They are appended. SQL calls this `INSERT`, but physically it's an append operation. That's trivial, as nothing needs to be compared, copied or moved around. For the table itself, it hardly makes any difference if the row that you insert is row number 1 or row number 20 billion.

In an *index*, new entries must be *inserted at the right place*. Finding the right place is trivial, that's a read access operation between `O(C)` and `O(log2(n))`. Once the right place is found, the insert operation needs to perform an insertion. That is, moving all elements after the insert position by one position towards the end. The complexity of the `INSERT` thus is `O(n)`.

A pre-sorted `PRIMARY KEY`, that is the `INSERT` operations performed in the sequence of the `PRIMARY KEY`, is not guaranteed to speed up the `INSERT` operation. It would only speed up the `INSERT` operation if the `PRIMARY KEY` is a plain array, it does not speed if the `PRIMARY KEY` is hashed, because without knowing the hashing function used it is seemingly random.

### How the Datatype of the `PRIMARY KEY` influences speed

For the `PRIMARY KEY` I would always use something which is a 32 bit value, if 4 billion rows are sufficient, or a 64 bit value otherwise. The simple reason is that on a 64 bit machine, comparing a 32 or 64 bit value is trivial. That basically boils down to a single CPU instruction, `cmp` on many CPUs. If you use `VARCHAR`, the comparison of is far more complex. It needs to compare a String byte by byte. Depending on the DBMS, the Locale settings and the Collation used, it might even be more complex than that.

### The special case of a fast `PRIMARY KEY`

A `PRIMARY KEY` of the form

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

would be fast because due to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` it's basically guaranteed that new keys are appended at the end of the index, and MySQL generates that new unique value itself.

### What you can do in your case

In case your 74G of data is pure, i.e. no duplicate keys, you can disable the PRIMARY KEY for the `INSERT` operation and re-enable it after the INSERT operation. That should speed up things significantly. There wouldn't be anything that slows down the insertion operation. And the creation of an `INDEX` afterwords has roughly the complexity of a sort operation.

Answer (score 0):

Via refactoring table structure, the insertion is speeded up drmatically. New table as follows:

```
+-------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | varchar(50)    | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| value | varchar(10000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dt    | int(11)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| uid   | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

If former table structure is used, moving data is so frequently. New table structure can avoid such actions. I post an experimental result comparing the insertion speed (data size = 1G).

```
+----------------+------------+
|  former table  | 30 minutes | 
+----------------+------------+
|  new table     | 5 minutes  |
+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: You might be able to speed up the `INSERT` operation further by defining the `Key` / `INDEX` for field `id` after the `INSERT` instead of before.

Answer (score 0):

we can further speed up insertion operation using sql :
"innsert into t1 (id,value,dt) values (XX,XX,XX),(XX,XX,XX),....(XX,XX,XX) on on duplicate key update value=values(value),dt=values(dt)" instead of "replace into  t1 values(XX,XX,XX),(XX,XX,XX),(XX,XX,XX),....(XX,XX,XX)", because such operation can avoid removing data at first